# using external jar dependency in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to create a web application on Netbeans by using Springboot which will generate all the necessary dependencies needed. My project will use an external API that I converted into a single jar class from https://github.com/coinapi/coinapi-sdk/tree/master/java-rest which was compiled into multiple class files and then into a single jar file called CoinAPI. I then added the jar to my local repository via

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=.\com\coinapi\CoinAPI.jar -DgroupId=com.coinapi
-DartifactId=CoinApi -Dversion=1.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

which was sucessfully added I then added this jar to my pom.xml which displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.alyxdev</groupId>
    <artifactId>CryptoStat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>CryptoStat</name>
    <description>CryptoCurrency Analytics</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.coinapi</groupId>
          <artifactId>CoinAPI</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

It successfully builds so I then try to utilize some of the classes inside the external library with the following:

```
package com.alyxdev.cryptostat;

import com.coinapi.java_rest_coin_api;



/**
 *
 * @author Alyx
 */
public class CoinAPIConnector {

    public CoinAPIConnector(){

    }
    public void initConnect(){

        java_rest_coin_api connect = new java_rest_coin_api("BEA6B82A-2489-4B5F-8B28-157A627DC8A1");

    }

}
```

however for some reason I get an error with my import which says "cannot find symbol: class java_rest_coin_api location: package com.coinapi"

I want to know if I am incorrectly using the external dependency when I import it or is my import somehow incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the solution to add the library as a dependency. I created a new java library project on netbeans (instead of building the jar on the command line and externally adding it to the project with mvn install) then I added the sources files there and then built the project to create the jar files. I then modified my pom.xml to an updated version of the project and finally went to the dependencies right click on the the jar and clicked on manually install artifact and found the jar on my netbeans workbench. After that I just had to refresh my project and the errors were gone.

Answer (score 0):

On the first look, your pom file looks good.
So I will suggest to open in your NetBeans the Project view and find the *Dependencies* item.
Then you can click on it, and search for your CoinAPI library. Then you can expand it and find out if the required class is on the list inside.

There's also another issue. The CoinAPI uses additional libraries: json-20140107.jar, okhttp-3.8.1.jar, okio-1.13.0.jar.

I bet you need to add them as dependencies to your pom file. Fortunately, most of them are already published on the central maven repo (at least ok libs).

Comment: I took a screenshot because I was kind of confused what you meant. http://puu.sh/zLXk2/f29c41d032.png under the CoinAPI-1.0.1.jar it lists the classes I was trying to use the java_rest_coin_api class, so wouldn't the import be correct?

Comment: On the screenshot, it looks like you have spaces around a dot in the import statement. Can you double check it?